# Problems installing ICub with YARP

Tags: cmake, installation, configure, yarp

I'm trying to follow the create icub makerfiles http://wiki.icub.org/wiki/Linux:Installation_from_sources but I have an error, and I've already followed all the steps

This is the error and I don't know what to do now...

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
   By not providing "FindYARP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "YARP", but
   CMake did not find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "YARP" (requested
   version 3.2.0) with any of the following names:

     YARPConfig.cmake
     yarp-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "YARP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "YARP_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "YARP"
   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
   installed.
```

Comment: If you compiled YARP correctly, you should have a `YARPConfig.cmake` file that was created in the YARP directory structure. The error message is saying it wasn't found. Does this file exist? Did you try setting `YARP_DIR` to the YARP directory containing this file, as it suggests?

Comment: To set the `YARP_DIR`, you can pass it in via the `-D` command line option: `cmake -DYARP_DIR=/your/path/to/yarp ..`

Answer (score 0):

CMake is looking for the `YARPConfig.cmake` file, that cannot be found in one of the searched paths.

If you didn't install YARP, that's the problem.
If you did, then it depends on how you installed it.

- If you installed YARP from the binary packages, it should be found automatically.
- If you built YARP from sources and installed it in a "standard" location (i.e. `/usr` or `/usr/local` on Linux) it should be found automatically.
- if you built YARP from sources and installed it in a non-standard location (`<installation prefix>`) you can choose one of these options :

  1. Set the  `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable to `<installation prefix>` (recommended if you are planning to install more than one package in the same path).
  2. Set the `YARP_DIR` environment variable to the `<installation prefix>/lib/cmake/YARP`
  3. Pass the `-DYARP_DIR=<installation prefix>/lib/cmake/YARP` to `cmake`
  4. Run `ccmake` instead of `cmake`, search for `YARP_DIR` and set it to `<installation prefix>/lib/cmake/YARP`
- If you built YARP from sources (in the folder `<build folder>`) and did not install it, you can choose one of these options:

  1. Set the `YARP_DIR` environment variable to the `<build folder>`
  2. Pass the `-DYARP_DIR=<build folder>` to `cmake`
  3. Run `ccmake` instead of `cmake`, search for `YARP_DIR` and set it to `<build folder>`